# Search for an item in inner array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an assoc array looking like this (the data comes from user input, this is just an example)

```
$startingDate = "2020-10-20";
$daysBetween[] = "2020-10-21", "2020-10-22", "2020-10-23";
$endingDate = "2020-10-24";
$eventDates[ID] => [
     "startingDate" => $startingDate,
     "daysBetween"  => $daysBetween,
     "endingDate"   => $endingDate, 
];
```

How would I look for a specific `startingDate` for example if I don't want to loop over every ID. Basically I'm looking for a way to do something like `$eventDates[*]["startingDate"]`

Comment: Well if you don't want to loop, u'd need to know the `id` in advance right?

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid, but if there is no other way, I'll do that.

Comment: Can you show some example data with expected result?

Comment: you will still need to loop through the array to find a match. Even if you know the id you still need to check if the id exists in the array to avoid possible errors.

Comment: @Jonny, U don't need to loop the array if you know the id? You just use `isset` or `$array[$id]['value'] ?? null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this a few different ways, one being `array_filter()`.

```php
$searchFor = '2020-09-20';
$result = array_filter($eventDates, function($v) use ($searchFor) {
    return ($v['startingDate'] ?? null) == $searchFor;
});
```

This returns the array(s) where you match the `$searchFor` variable with a column `startingDate`. If you just want the first one, use `$result = array_shift($result);` to get the first one.

This approach basically filters out any results where the callback doesn't return `true`. By including `use ($searchFor)` the variable becomes visible inside the scope of that function, otherwise it would be undefined within that scope.

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/iaT8k

Answer (score 0):

The questioner states that they are looking for a way to do something like
`$eventDates[*]["startingDate"]`

The PHP equivalent to this is:

```
foreach ($eventDates as $id => $eventDate) {
  //look at $eventDate["startingDate"] and if it matches the criteria do whatever required
  //you know the ID (=$id) so you can save/return/use that if needed.
}
```

Comment: OP also stated he didn't want to write a loop